# In what use cases is a web service likely to receive OPTIONS requests other than CORS?

Tags: http, cors

I have recently implemented a CORS IDispatchMessageInspector applied through a BehaviorExtensionElement for services within a large project I am working on to allow for CORS support (arising from calling REST WCF web services from jQuery Ajax calls).

The current implementation intercepts all OPTIONS method calls to an endpoint with the CORS behavior specified and responds with the appropriate headers (and a 200). As it stands the service will expect to see OPTIONS requests only in the case of CORS requests, however I cannot guarantee that this will always be the case.

In the interests of future proofing and extensibility, what are the most common reasons for OPTIONS requests outside of CORS? Are there plans to extend the use of such requests in future WC3 specs ([as this seems to suggest](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html))? Are there any use cases that I should attempt to allow for?

Comment: @SalmanZaidi `inline code` (\``) is meant for inline code, not for higlighting random words.

Comment: note: the HTTP spec is not a W3C spec; you're just looking at the copy of the IETF spec...

Comment: Yes you're entirely right there, standards mix up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the other way around.

A [CORS preflight request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request) will be an OPTIONS request including an `Origin` and `Access-Control-Request-Method` request header, by which you can recognize it as such.

Any other OPTIONS request is just that, and can be sent by any client for any reason.

Comment: I'm aware of how CORS works and have implemented a solution to deal with these requests. Maybe my question wasn't clear, but my implementation responds to all OPTIONS requests presuming that they are CORS pre-flights as there are no other OPTIONS requests expected within the services. Could this lead to issues?

Comment: @Swires theoretically it could. HTTP clients are free to send whatever they want in this regard. If a client decides to prepend each request with an OPTIONS request to detect certain capabilities, it can. Your code should not assume each OPTIONS request is a CORS preflight request.

Comment: So in practice I may be better off detecting the options method || something like the presence of access-control headers to ensure that the request is in fact pre-flight for a CORS implementation?

Comment: @Swires that seems the way to go, because the spec states those headers must be present. :)

Comment: Ok thanks for this, marking answer to reflect comments, and modifying conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

WebDAV clients are known to use OPTIONS to probe for support for protocol levels and method support (see RFC 4918).